# loop for string not use & while loop body use &

Tags: c++, string

```
#include "iostream"

int main()
{
  std::string s = "abc";
  for ( const auto& item : s ) {
    std::cout << &item << std::endl;
  }
}
```

the resulst is
abc
bc
c

```
#include "iostream"

int main()
{
  std::string s = "abc";
  for ( const auto item : s ) {
    std::cout << &item << std::endl;
  }
}
```

then println strange words,but the first word is right

what is the difference between the two ablove code blocks?

Comment: Do you know what `&` means?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, it's the adress of the character in the string

Comment: In the first case, you are printing a `char*` pointer pointing into the block of characters managed by `s`; that block of characters is nul-terminated. In the second case, you have a temporary `char` variable, take an address of that variable, and treat it as a pointer to a nul-terminated string - but it's not. The program then exhibits undefined behavior by way of a buffer overrun.

Comment: And do you know what happens when you pass an address of a character to `<<` of an output stream?

Comment: Yes so what do you expect it to print a character or an address?

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer, expect printing same with the first block

Comment: Ok so even if both `const auto& item` and  `&item` use `&` that `&` does different things.  `const auto& item` sets up a const reference to an item and for the rest of the code it will then "look like" that item. In the second case `&` returns the address of the item. So it might be a bit tricky to learn but the meaning of `&` is context sensitive.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik, it will print characters  of the adress and next to   until touch  nul-terminated

Comment: Yeah, and `const auto item` is a lone character, there's nothing next to it.

Comment: In the second example you are passing the address of the `item` variable to `operator<<` not the address of anything in the string. That only happens in the first example.

Comment: Correct, so what exactly about the observed results are unclear to you?

Comment: `static_cast<void const*>(&item)` to print the address of the item.  Assuming that is your intent.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik , the second block code `item` is a copy of the character , not the character of `s` ,i was confused about this ,now i get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` can be used for different things.

- `0xF0 & 0x0F` --> `&` is the bitwise and
- `true && false` --> `&&` is the Boolean/logical and
- `int var{0}; &var;` --> `&` is the address-of operator and returns the address of the object or a pointer to the object you use it on.
- `int& sameVar{var};` --> `&` creates a reference called `sameVar` which is bound to `var`. With it you can access `var` and modify it as if you had the "real" `var`.

You use the address-of operator in each `std::cout` statement which returns a `char*` (pointer to a `char`). When printing something like an `int*` with `std::cout` it will output its address which could look like this: `000000734F9CF8D4`. However `char*`s are something special in the C and C++ language since they are used to represent c-strings. `std::cout` will print all following `char`s beginning from the memory address you gave it until it hits a `\0` which is the NUL terminator for c-strings.

---

In the first block of code you use

```
for ( const auto& item : s )
// which is the same as
for ( const char& item : s)

// you could imagine the loop like this:
for (int i{ 0 }; i < s.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << &s[i] << std::endl;
}
```

This  means that each `item` references a `char` in your `std::string s`. In the first iteration `item == s[0]` would be true and also `&item == &s[0]` would be true. In the following iterations those two statements would still be true if you incremented the index in each iteration. That means you will print a c-string each iteration, but advancing the first `char` you print each time. Therefore you get the output:

```
abc
bc
c
```

---

In the second block of code you use

```
for ( const auto item : s )
// which is the same as
for ( const char item : s)

// you could imagine the loop like this:
for (int i{ 0 }; i < s.size(); i++) {
    char copy{ s[i] };
    std::cout << &copy << std::endl;
}
```

This  means that each `item` now is a copy of a `char` in `s`. `item == s[0]` would still be true, but `&item == &s[0]` would not be true since these are both different objects. The same goes for the following iterations and incrementing the index. Because you don't actually know the address of `item` here and what comes after it you should not print it like this. Since `std::cout` will continue printing `char`s until it reaches a `\0` you will get some random garbage results.

Comment: *"you will get some random garbage results."* Pedantically, it is UB with out of bound access, so anything can happen. printing garbage is only one possibility.